# How can I search a right if it is in collection A and if isn't in collection B, with LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I need to search all rights which are in the roles.RolesWithRights collection  and are not in collection role.RolesWithRights, after this I should switch searches and delete rights which I found in roles.RolesWithRights and add in roles.RolesWithRights all find rights.

I tried to do this with foreach() syntax, but I think with LINQ will be better, but I do not how. Can someone help me please. 
Below is something what I tried.

```
foreach (RolesWithRights rights in role.RolesWithRights) {
    if (!roles.RolesWithRights.Any(y => y.ApplicationRightsId == rights.ApplicationRightsId)) {
        roles.RolesWithRights.Remove(rights);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Finding the exclusive elements
var onlyInRoles = roles.RolesWithRights.Except(role.RolesWithRights);
//adding to role and delete from roles
onlyInRoles.forEach(x => {
role.RolesWithRights.Add(x);
roles.RoleWIthRights.Remove(x);
});
```

You can actually combine those 2 calls in one

```
roles.RolesWithRights.Except(role.RolesWithRights).forEach(x => {
role.RolesWithRights.Add(x);
roles.RoleWIthRights.Remove(x);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this with LINQ then you need to look the `Except()` and `Intersect()` LINQ methods -

Except() - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx

Intersect() - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.110).aspx